# why the point $b_0 =(1,0)$ has no neighborhood $U$

Tags: algebraic-topology

The map $p : \mathbb{R}_{+}  \to S^1$  given by the equation  $p(x)=(\cos 2 \pi x , \sin 2\pi x) $ is surjective and local homeomorphism   .But it   is  not a covering map

Here Munkres  say that  the point  $b_0 =(1,0)$ has  no neighborhood $U$ that is evenly  covered by $p$

**My confusion**: why the point  $b_0 =(1,0)$ has  no neighborhood $U$

**My thinking** : Take  $p^{-1}(U)=\{ x \in \mathbb{R_{+}} | \cos 2 \pi x >0\}=\bigcup V_n= \cup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} ( n -1/4, n+1/4)$  This implies $b_0 =(1,0)$ has   neighborhood $U$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any neighbourhood of the point $\left( 1, 0 \right)$ will contain elements from "below" the $X$-axis and "above" the $X$-axis. Therefore, its inverse image under $p$ will be of the form $(0, \epsilon)$ along with $\left( n - \delta, n + \delta \right)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The particular set $\left( 0, \epsilon \right)$ cannot be homeomorphic to a neighbourhood of $\left( 1, 0 \right)$ since its image under $p$ does not contain $\left( 1, 0 \right)$.

In your thinking what you have missed is that the inverse image is always $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \left( n - \dfrac{1}{4}, n + \dfrac{1}{4} \right) \cap \mathbb{R}_+$. Now there is the problem that I mentioned before.

For intuition, look here:

[image]

Comment: No, no. I meant the "X-axis". For better understanding, I have also included the figure to indicate what those words mean.